# converting lodash's pickby in to javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

how can I make lodash's pickby function in javascript? I have found the following one in "you don't need lodash"

```
function pickBy(object) {
    const obj = {};
    for (const key in object) {
        if (object[key] !== null && object[key] !== false && object[key] !== undefined) {
            obj[key] = object[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

but wondering other implementations

Comment: you miss the optional predicate. but why do you have all the checks?

Comment: Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, x) => callback(obj[x]) ? { ...prev, [x] : obj[x] } : prev , {});

Answer (score 4):

You could add a predicate function, as [`_.pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pickBy) describes and use the entries and filter the data and build a new object.

```
function pickBy(object, predicate = v => v) {
    return Object.assign(
        ...Object
            .entries(object)
            .filter(([, v]) => predicate(v))
            .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pickBy), you can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). If the predicate returns a truthy answer for the value, assign the key and value to the result object.

Note: if you need `_.pickBy()`, and you don't want to entire lodash package, you can import the [pickBy module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pickby).

```js
function pickBy(object, predicate = v => v) {
  const obj = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
    if (predicate(value)) obj[key] = value;
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(pickBy({ a: 1, b: 0, c: 3 }));
console.log(pickBy({ a: 1, b: 0, c: 3 }, v => v < 3 ));
```

Now days you can get the entries, filter by the value, and convert back to an object with [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const pickBy = (object, predicate = v => v) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).filter(([, v]) => predicate(v)))

console.log(pickBy({ a: 1, b: 0, c: 3 }));
console.log(pickBy({ a: 1, b: 0, c: 3 }, v => v < 3 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Being

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };
```

and callback a method which is applied just to the values of the object (_.isNumber):

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, x) => callback(obj[x]) ? { ...prev, [x] : obj[x] } : prev , {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nina's solution fails when the object is `{}`.
Here is mine:

```
const pickBy = (object, predicate = v => v) =>
  Object.entries(object)
    .filter(([k, v]) => predicate(v))
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: v }), {});
```